# Ignition lead plug end has white residue on one lead, what could be the cause?

Tags: ignition, hyundai

[image: Ignition lead]

I have a 1997 Hyundai Lantra 1.8l
While I was replacing the spark plugs a discolored lead was discovered.
The 4 plugs were all the same age and appearance.
What could cause this

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's a sign you've had electrical leakage from the spark plug lead. If you're changing the leads due to some intermittent misses, this is the reason why. If some of the energy is getting bled off to ground instead of through the spark plug, you're engine isn't going to running as good as it should. Since you're changing them, you'll probably find the vehicle will be running a lot better.